# Correct way to change error file location and run jar

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to change where any error files for a java program will be output to. From what I have researched and gather the following seems correct `java -XX:ErrorFile=/foo -jar foo.jar`. However since my program does not error so no dump file is created (the error file specification is there in case any ever happens) I am not sure if the syntax is correct. Does the syntax look correct for changing the output of the error file then running the jar file I want, or will an issue be caused? Currently running 1.7.65 on Red Hat 6.5

Comment: you cannot use -cp with -jar option

Comment: how would i set the class path then without changing the environment variable?

Comment: use a building tool like maven

Comment: could another solution be to add the wildcard * to the jar's manifest?

Comment: if i was to set the `classpath` variable to `/lib/foo`/ and run the jar, would java be able to find the library files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use -classpath with -jar option
However you can use maven to have the dependencies for you jar like this

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>well.defined.path.of.the.mainClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: how would i do this in ant?